# How to organize the reducers in a big normalized Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, normalizr

I had read the official documentation on the Redux site, some articles online and some question here on StackOverflow about this topic, but i still can't figure out how to organize my states.

I normalized then because some entities have references to the same object, and dealing with this would become problematic.

So, after normalization, this is my state:

```
state: {
    measurementSystems: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    measurementUnits: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    sameTypeUnitConverters: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    bodyMeasurementTypes: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    bodyMeasurements: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    bodyMeasurementShortcutSettings: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    uniqueBodyMeasurements: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    nutritionalTables: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    dataSources: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    foodGroups: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    foods: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    diaryEntries: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    mealSettings: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    goals: { 0: {}, 1: {} },
    users: { 0: {}, 1: {} }
};
```

**My question is**: How to write the reducers for this normalized state? Should i write one reducer per state and make then deal with the same actions? Or should i create one reducer per action and make this reducer manage all the states?

If i have one reducer per state and send a action REMOVE_DIARY_ENTRY, for example. I will have to make all states that have reference in a diaryEntry to treat this action and check if they need to remove a deleted reference. But how i would do these checks?

Otherwise, if i have one reducer per action, these reducers can start to do very similar tasks and become very coupled with the current state architecture.

**THIS PART IS JUST FOR CLARIFICATION**

Here is what they mean (its a app to track what you eat):

- A **diaryEntry** represents a **food** in the diary; A **food** is in a **foodGroup,** that has a **dataSource.** A food also have a **nutritionalTable** and a **measurementUnit**;
- **MeasurementSystems**, **measurementUnits** and **sameTypeUnitConverter** are used to store precise information of measures like cm, meter and pounds.
- **BodyMeasurementTypes**, **bodyMeasurements** and **uniqueBodyMeasurements** are used to track the user measurements, like the chest size for example.
- **MealSettings** and **bodyMeasurementShortcutSettings** are settings of the app UI.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to first think what actions will be dispatched to store and how store info will be consumed. This allows you to decide how to better split store.

1. Actions can be dispatched and store consumed from components which will want to display and modify store in response to user iterations. For example you may have table or list to display **diaryEntries** to user and another - to display **bodyMeasurements**. And user may want to set **bodyMeasurements** or add **diaryEntry**. As a result, you may consider grouping **diaryEntries**, **food** and related entities in one part of store and **bodyMeasurements** in another. (This can be logical division based on how data is consumed by React components)
2. **MeasurementSystems** and **measurementUnits** may not be modifiable by user (they may be set by admin or preloaded in db). So they can be considered catalogs and put in separate part of store named `Catalogs`. They can be loaded from back end with `REQUEST_CATALOGS` and `RECEIVE_CATALOGS` actions and stay read-only in app.
3. List of **Users** can be third part of store if for example it can be modified by admin of app. Or it can be separated from other parts
4. **goals** can also be separate part of store as they can be displayed in some other part of your app (not in part where **diaryEntries** or **bodyMeasurements** displayed). And user may be allowed to set his/her goals. So it better to put **goals** in forth part.

Another approach can be to think how entities will be fetched from back-end and saved back. If it is better to fetch all entities at once, you may leave all of them in one part of store. May be separating only read-only entities from writable ones. And have universal actions like `CHANGE_ENTITY` which will carry `entityType` in payload. `entityType` will be `diaryEntries` or `bodyMeasurements` or anything else user wants to modify.

For example

```
{ type: 'CHANGE_ENTITY', entityType: 'diaryEntries', key: 0, value: 'some value' }
```

With such approach all store can be monolithic.

Comment: @Flyodor thanks for the answer, i agree with everything! But i was looking for more details on the reducers implementation. Example: Currently i have one reducer per state and treat the actions on them. For actions that affects more than one entity i have created a sharedActions file and have actions like DELETE_DIARY_ENTRY_AND_REMOVE_FOOD: In this action i include the ids of the diaryEntry and the food i want to remove, so i can treat this action on the diaryEntries and in the foods reducer (and search for references to check if is ok to remove it). Can you share how you usually do this?